# how to check whether the value is inserted or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using DataSetTableAdapters for inserting data.how can i check whether the value is inserted or not..I want to show the error or success message after completion of inserting..

My partial code is here:

```
     DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inempleaveTableAdapter TA = new DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_inempleaveTableAdapter();
     TA.GetData(ddlperiod.SelectedItem.Text, lblid.Text, name, leave_value);
```

How can i display the success message (or) error message after the above step...

Comment: Do you mean populating the DataSet or inserting data into the data source?

Comment: insert data into database table ..

Comment: Assuming the sp_inempleaveTableAdapter is an insert stored procedure and it returns the new data after insertion, what does the TA.GetData return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the GetData() method returns a table adapter class that inherits from the DataTable. Thanks to this, GetData() gives you access to regular operations performed on a table.

So if you compare the row counts before or after or even if the result is larger than 0 
e.g. `GetData().Rows.Count > 0` you can raise an event or show a MessageBox depending on your type of applicatoin.

Also please check out this link Table [Adapters and DataSets](http://www.functionx.com/vb/adonet/ta.htm)